# Calculus: Determine whether an integral is convergent or divergent

Tags: calculus, integration

So I got this math problem, and I have to find out if it is convergent or divergent. If it converges the I have to solve it.

$$\int_0^{1}\frac{1}{x\ln(x)}dx$$

I know that I have to split it up, so here is how I did it:

$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{x\ln(x)}dx+\int_\frac{1}{2}^{1}\frac{1}{x\ln(x)}dx$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is fine; now show that at least one of these integrals diverges.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\ln(x) \leq x$ for $x \in (0,\infty)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what is the derivative of $\log(\log x)$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=e^t$ : $\int_0^1 {{1 \over {x\ln x}}} \;dx\buildrel {x = {e^t}} \over \longrightarrow \int_{ - \infty }^0 {{1 \over t}} \;dt$

$\int_{ - \infty }^0 {{1 \over t}} \;dt \longrightarrow divergent$

It seems that splitting it up doesn't bring much.